# How to slice a mesh with geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

In Blender 2.93.5, I'm trying to create a geometry node group which slices a mesh along a regular array of parallel planes. I can get the desired effect by intersecting with a cube with an array modifier:

[image: Intersect with cube with array modifier]

However that doesn't allow me to calculate the array count within the node group. Instead of the array modifier, I tried using `Point Instance` to create cube instances along a line. The resulting output is empty. After tweaking the offset a bit (see below) I think I figured out what's happening: I want a 2-way intersection of (input geometry) with (array of n cubes), but this is producing an (n+1)-way intersection of the input geometry and all the cubes. Since the cubes are disjoint, the result is empty.

[image: Intersect with line of cube instances]

Is there a way to fix this? I tried adding a `Join Geometry` node after the `Point Instance`, but it didn't seem to make a difference.

[image]

Comment: can u provide blend file?

Comment: @Chris I added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you right, you want to cut an array with another array.

So a very simple setup works like this:

[image]

The cutter ist just a very flattened box.

[image]

result:

[image]

without boolean:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The key was to subtract width 0 cubes, rather than intersect with adjacent cubes.