# Slicing object into multiple parts using geometry nodes so I can perform actions on each separate sliced object

Tags: geometry-nodes, 3d-printing, instances

Slicing object into multiple parts using geometry nodes so I can perform actions on each separate sliced object.

**Example:**  I have a cone that I would like to split it into multiple parts and add connectors to each of them separately.

[image: img1]

1. A Boolean difference on the cone using a cube to create slices of a given size.

[image: img2]

2. Separating each object into **mesh islands** objects.
   `Not sure how to fully do this.`
3. Then adding connectors to the outer edge of each slice of the mesh islands.
   `Not sure how to fully do this.`

[image: img3]

How can I a separate the cone into mesh islands objects to perform a separate action on each island (adding connectors to the outer edge of each slice of the mesh islands.).

PS. This will be 3D printed.  I'm testing slicing up an object into multiple parts and adding some connectors to the outer edges so the slices can be connected together.

I did look at [How to slice a mesh with geometry nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/245471/how-to-slice-a-mesh-with-geometry-and)  and [How to cut a mesh into a flexible number of pieces along a certain axis?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/279201/how-to-cut-a-mesh-into-a-flexible-number-of-pieces-along-a-certain-axis)

[image: img4]

Attached Blend File below.

[image]

Comment: What are the rules concerning the amount of instances, depending on the cut (island) size?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by rules... But I'm testing with 2 to 6 cuts / slices (Mesh islands) each island would be about 1mm to 5mm in height/thickness.  As for the connectors, each slice would have 10 connectors attached to it.

Comment: But 10 may be too large, for a small ring, don't you think?

Comment: Your right, I made the test cone bigger and updated the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

With these nodes completing the part that creates the disk:

[image]

What it does:

The node group (see below) calculates mean radius and center of each disk.

Then it captures these values on each face.

Tranforms the faces to points, place these points at the previously calculated centers and merge in order to have 1 point per disk.

Instance on point with a curve, scaled by the previously calculated radii.

Realize to get ride of the scales.

Resample in order to have the wanted amount of "F-snap".

Instance them and align Y along curve normals.

Shift them a bit (their origin is not at center).

Boolean union with the disks.

---

The node group (before the captures):

[image]

Accumulate by island index three things (from faces): the lengths, the positions, the face count.

So that we can calculate average radii and centers.

---

[image] (Blender 4.0)

Comment: Rick T, as you're asking a new question, maybe you could indicate if the answer to this one is correct or not.